# Asignación, Agrupación, Distribución de una variable

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera preguntar pues estoy realizando un programa en R con los siguientes datos como ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es un código que me permita sumar las cantidades de la derecha creando una nueva variable por ejemplo (asignación y coloque [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LECm.png) cuando la suma de las cantidades alcance 500,asignación coloque [2] excluyendo los 500 sumados anteriores y luego, [3], [4] etc hasta iterar toda la columna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola!

Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te aconsejo que leas las instrucciones para realizar una pregunta y que los usuarios podamos ayudarte en lo que podamos.

Referente a la pregunta que planteas, supongamos que tu tabla se llama `df` y tus columnas `lugar` y `n`.

La función `cumsum(df$n)` te devolverá el acumulado de la suma de los valores de tu columna `n`, por tanto, si divides entre 500 esta cantidad, podrás ver cuándo alcanzas las 500 unidades (cuando la parte entera cambie de valor). Así pues, el siguiente comando te devolverá una variable que agrupe los individuos en grupos hasta sumar más de 500 unidades.

```
df$grupo <- floor(cumsum(df$n)/500) + 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias si me sirvio y tomare encuenta los consejos